# Problem using Atmosphere with Glassfish v3 and Primefaces

Tags: primefaces, comet, glassfish-3, atmosphere

am trying to create a chat app using primefaces ajax push/comet which needs Atmosphere to run.am using glassfish v3 as my web server.but when i start up the chat app and try to chat i get this exception.

WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Comet Servlet]: PWC1382: Allocate exception for servlet Comet Servlet
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access field org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.atmosphereHandlers from class org.primefaces.comet.PrimeFacesCometServlet.

please can anyone help cos my deadline for the project is fast approaching.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is on the PrimeFacesforum: 
http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3117&start=0

Comment: Cagatay changed the prime faces forum URL without redirects. :( The new URL is http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3117&start=0 which just says to use atmosphere 0.5